# how to authenticate user after success-full registration using doorkeeper gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, doorkeeper, sorcery

I am working on project that is using `doorkeeper` gem.
I have setup everything  successfully.
Now what i want to do is to logged the user in after successful registration.I am using `sorcery` gem for authentication .

My registration process is working fine and i am getting `access_token` from doorkeeper.

But i cant't logging in the user with `doorkeeper` gem.

Here is my `users_controller.rb`

```
 def create
  profile = Profile.new(params.permit(:birth_date, :phone_number))
  user = profile.build_user(params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password))

  if profile.save
    @access_token = Doorkeeper::AccessToken.create!(
      resource_owner_id: user.id,
      application_id: doorkeeper_token.application_id,
      use_refresh_token: Doorkeeper.configuration.refresh_token_enabled?,
      expires_in: Doorkeeper.configuration.access_token_expires_in
    )
    #This line is for authentication provided by sorcery gem
    @user = User.authenticate( params[:email], params[:password])
  else
    error!(:unprocessable_entity, metadata: { details: profile.errors })
  end
end
```

I have tried using doorkeeper provided `resource_owner_from_credentials` method at my users_controller.rb for login but still i failed like below:

```
Doorkeeper.resource_owner_from_credentials do
  User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
end
```

Can any tell me how to login the user after successful registration with doorkeeper and sorcery gem.

thank you very much.